# C# Get type of my form to check if it is open

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a generic method to check if a form is open. 
But I can not make the OfType work, I tried to use a get type of my parameter variable.

```
    private void OpenForm(Form myForm)
    {

        if (!Application.OpenForms.OfType<GetType??>().Any())
        {
            myForm.MdiParent = this;
            myForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            myForm.Show();
        }
    }
```

How can I get the type of the parameter and used in the OfType?

Comment: This is a very broken approach, it requires you to first create the form object before you can test if it is already shown.  The argument should be `Type` so you can pass, say, `typeof(Form2)`.  Now it is simple of course.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will update my code taking this is consideration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your method with type parameters to make it generic.

```
private void OpenForm<T>(T myForm) where T : Form
{
    if (!Application.OpenForms.OfType<T>().Any())
    {
        myForm.MdiParent = this;
        myForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        myForm.Show();
    }
}
```

For more information about generic methods, consult MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx

Comment: I added advice on how to make a method generic and a link to MSDN documentation on generic methods. Hope that makes my post not "low quality." For future reference, clear guidance on what makes a post "low quality" would be helpful.